# ACL entity and microservices database relations

Tags: database, microservices, authentication, relational-database

I would like to build a microservices architecture to handle the following scenario:
I have a building. The building has some kinds of devices. And the devices can be used by the users. In the system, the administrator can add a user and allow the user to use selected devices in the building.

I have *user service*, *device service*, *building service*, *authentication service*. Each service has own database. The problem is where to store relations between users and buildings, buildings and devices?

To indicate which user has access to the device I need to store relation: *device_id - user_id* but it should be in the table *devices_users* in the *user service* or in *device service*? The same for the relation *building_id - user_id* and *device_id - building_id*. Could anyone help my with this issue? Maybe I have designed the microservices in wrong way?

Comment: Why did you split this simple scenario into four services?

Comment: I have no experience in microservices architecture and I split it based on domains/entities. So each microservice handle each type of entity. Maybe I should split it another way...

Comment: A domain usually does not contain a single entity. It looks like the entities belong to the same domain. In this case I would not split at all but implement a single service that handles this domain.

Comment: So should I have one microservice that handles users data, devices data, building data and relations between them? It seems to simple for microservices architecture at all, isn't it?